# NullPointerException when setting layout_height to match_parent in a tablerow

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception

I am using a table to display textviews, and ran into this problem: [image]

Where the backgrounds of the textviews do not occupy the full space. I set their `layout_height` to `match_parent`, but that caused a NullPointerException, (onMeasure error in Android Studio)

What is causing this?

Here is an example of one of the textviews:

```
<TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/highEleven"
                        android:id="@+id/highOneOne"
                        android:layout_column="2"
                        android:background="@color/blueRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp" />
```

The whole XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="aetherum.com.take5init.riskAssessment"
android:minWidth="300dp"
>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">



        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView" >

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Severity of Incident"
                        android:id="@+id/textView17"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:layout_span="6"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:gravity="center" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Likelihood of incident"
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:outlineProvider="bounds"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Low"
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_column="2"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightGrey" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Minor"
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_column="3"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightGrey" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Moderate"
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_column="4"
                        android:background="@color/lightGrey"
                        android:padding="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Major"
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_column="5"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightGrey" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Critical"
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_column="6"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightGrey" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Almost \nCertain"
                        android:id="@+id/textView8"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightGrey" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/highEleven"
                        android:id="@+id/highOneOne"
                        android:layout_column="2"
                        android:background="@color/blueRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/highSixteen"
                        android:id="@+id/highTwoOne"
                        android:layout_column="3"
                        android:background="@color/blueRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/extremeTwenty"
                        android:id="@+id/extremeThreeOne"
                        android:layout_column="4"
                        android:background="@color/redRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/extremeTwentyThree"
                        android:id="@+id/extremeFourOne"
                        android:layout_column="5"
                        android:background="@color/redRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/extremeTwentyFive"
                        android:id="@+id/extremeFiveOne"
                        android:layout_column="6"
                        android:background="@color/redRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Likely"
                        android:id="@+id/textView9"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightGrey" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/moderateSeven"
                        android:id="@+id/moderateOneTwo"
                        android:layout_column="2"
                        android:background="@color/greenRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:padding="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/highTwelve"
                        android:id="@+id/highTwoTwo"
                        android:layout_column="3"
                        android:background="@color/blueRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:padding="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/highSeventeen"
                        android:id="@+id/highThreeTwo"
                        android:layout_column="4"
                        android:background="@color/blueRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:padding="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/extremeTwentyOne"
                        android:id="@+id/extremeFourTwo"
                        android:layout_column="5"
                        android:background="@color/redRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:padding="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/extremeTwentyFour"
                        android:id="@+id/extremeFiveTwo"
                        android:layout_column="6"
                        android:background="@color/redRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:padding="5dp" />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Possible"
                        android:id="@+id/textView10"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightGrey" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/lowFour"
                        android:id="@+id/lowOneThree"
                        android:layout_column="2"
                        android:background="@color/yellowRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:padding="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/moderateEight"
                        android:id="@+id/moderateTwoThree"
                        android:layout_column="3"
                        android:background="@color/greenRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:padding="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/highThirteen"
                        android:id="@+id/highThreeThree"
                        android:layout_column="4"
                        android:background="@color/blueRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:padding="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/extremeEighteen"
                        android:id="@+id/extremeFourThree"
                        android:layout_column="5"
                        android:background="@color/redRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:padding="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/extremeTwentyTwo"
                        android:id="@+id/extremeFiveThree"
                        android:layout_column="6"
                        android:background="@color/redRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:padding="5dp" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Unlikely"
                        android:id="@+id/textView11"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightGrey" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/lowTwo"
                        android:id="@+id/lowOneFour"
                        android:layout_column="2"
                        android:background="@color/yellowRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:padding="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/lowFive"
                        android:id="@+id/lowTwoFour"
                        android:layout_column="3"
                        android:background="@color/yellowRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:padding="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/moderateNine"
                        android:id="@+id/moderateThreeFour"
                        android:layout_column="4"
                        android:background="@color/greenRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:padding="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/highFourteen"
                        android:id="@+id/highFourFour"
                        android:layout_column="5"
                        android:background="@color/blueRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:padding="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/extremeEighteen"
                        android:id="@+id/extremeFiveFour"
                        android:layout_column="6"
                        android:background="@color/redRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:padding="5dp" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Rare"
                        android:id="@+id/textView12"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightGrey" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/lowOne"
                        android:id="@+id/lowOneFive"
                        android:layout_column="2"
                        android:background="@color/yellowRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:padding="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/lowThree"
                        android:id="@+id/lowTwoFive"
                        android:layout_column="3"
                        android:background="@color/yellowRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:padding="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/moderateSix"
                        android:id="@+id/moderateThreeFive"
                        android:layout_column="4"
                        android:background="@color/greenRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:padding="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/highTen"
                        android:id="@+id/highFourFive"
                        android:layout_column="5"
                        android:background="@color/blueRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:padding="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/highFifteen"
                        android:id="@+id/highFiveFive"
                        android:layout_column="6"
                        android:background="@color/blueRisk"
                        android:autoText="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:padding="5dp" />
                </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

StackTrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.LinearLayout.forceUniformHeight(LinearLayout.java:1409)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1397)
at android.widget.TableRow.onMeasure(TableRow.java:113)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
at android.widget.TableLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(TableLayout.java:461)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:473)
at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:436)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(HorizontalScrollView.java:1259)
```

Comment: Also see [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

Comment: what value are you using, in the posted code is  `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` but you said that you use `match_parent`

Comment: Neither works, and as `fill_parent` is now deprecated it returns exactly the same as `match_parent`

Comment: You need to post the complete xml and stack trace

Comment: Stack trace is trimmed a bit as I hit the 30000 character limit, but the trimmed part is just the IDE part